# Send email to correspending email address

Tags: php

I have added a modal box through the modal.js like bellow.

```
<div class="modal current" id="ex1" style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -217px; margin-left: -235px; z-index: 2; display: block;">
<p>Thank you for adding a new word in the dictionary.
</p><p>Tell your friends</p><input type="\&quot;email\&quot;" placeholder="Enter your friend's email address"><input type="Submit" value="Send" name="Submit"><p><a href="http://verbalage.com/index.php/advertise" target="_blank">Advertise with us</a></p>
```

Now i want send email to the email id , which is in the email input box. How is possible ?

Comment: I think you have to type some codes on the computer for this.

Comment: or move some binary digits from your bank account to another's

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a `name` for your input

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your friend's email address">
```

In php, using mail() function make it's possible, like:

```
<?php
// receive the email address from form
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

In some cases the mail function does not work on localhost.

More about [php mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score -2):

PHP's mail function can help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: @Dagon That probably applies for links to blogs or personal sites, which might go offline. I can't imagine linking to php's own documentation would be discouraged.